# Create project specific files in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I'm wondering if it is possible to create project-specific files in Clearcase.  What I want to do is create files in one project, use Clearcase to source control the files, but I don't want those files to leave that porject because they don't have applicability in any other project.

For example:
I want to manage database changes in Clearcase.  I plan on having 3 folders in each project (projects are created for each release of the software).  The folders are "install", "update", and "backout".  The install folder contains the scripts needed to build a database from scratch for the stream that I'm working in, let's say the stream is in project "13.03".  The "update" and "backout" folders contain scripts needed to update and backout the changes to bring the database from 13.02 to 13.03, and vice versa.

In the 13.04 project, I'll have the same folder structure, but I don't want the contents of the "update" and "backout" folders in my 13.04 because I'll have other files that will bring the database from 13.03 to 13.04.

So what I'm looking to do is essentially create "project-specific" files/folders in Clearcase.

I'd gladly take any other recommendation for managing database changes in Clearcase.  Keep in mind that the 13.03 and 13.04 (for example) baselines could be being developed at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are referring to the same project, with different versions (13.02, 13.03, ...).
If that is the case:

- simply update your 3 folder according to the current version
- put a baseline (if we are talking about ClearCase UCM) on the component representing your project
- if evolutions needs to be done on any file of a specific version, make a child Stream called, for instance, "13.03", and update your "13.03" folders there. They will evolve in complete isolation in their own dedicated "13.03" *branch*.

---

If you *have to* create a new directory for each project version (which means you don't need a source control system at all, just a simple backup system), then you have no choice but to recreate each of those folders with their appropriate files in them, making new "add to source control".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over how the CM is structured.  Currently the organization I'm in will great a new project per release of software.

Comment: @Ben then you defeat the very purpose of a Version Control System. If you have a different version of a group of file, you create a new revision of it, in a branch if need be. You don't create a new directory, unless you want to go back to SCCS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System) back in seventies...

Comment: @Ben That being said, I have edited my answer with the consequence of your current structure management.